# will declaring window.variable in a function make the value global?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

Okay, so let's say that I have a global variable `myVar`, and in a function `myFunction()`, I write `myVar = 2;`. Normally, this will make `myVar` be equal to `2` **inside** the function. My question is, will declaring `window.myVar = 2` in the function make `myVar` equal to `2` **globally** (so, `alert(myVar)` outside the function returns `2`)?

Comment: That's not a declaration, it's an assignment to the property of the global object.

Comment: ^^ Agreed .. And being assigned to the global object it's accessible from anywhere ..

Comment: "*If I write `myVar = 2;` in a function, normally, this will make `myVar` be equal `2` inside that function*" - Nope. That's [when you use `var`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1470488/1048572).

Comment: Really? Because I just tested that in JSFiddle (my code: `var myVar;
function myFunction () {
    myVar = 2;
}
alert(myVar);` and it returns "undefined"

Comment: You have to call `myFunction` as well :)

Answer (score 3):

A quick review of global variables first:

Global variables declared using `var` or `let` behave differently. A global variable defined using `var` create a non-configurable property of the global object, using the name of the variable, which can't be deleted.

```js
var x = "var x";
console.log("window.x: " + window.x);
console.log( JSON.stringify(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, "x")))
```

But a global variable declared with `let` does not become a property of the global object. If you have a `window` property (in a browser) and a `let` variable of the same name, you have to qualify the window property with `window.` to access it:

```js
let y = "let y";
window.y = "window.y";
console.log("y = " + y + "( using the identifier only)");
console.log("window.y = " + window.y);
```

Now getting back to the question,

1. If you declare `myVar` in global scope and reference it within a function, you will access the global variable, **provided** you have not re-declared the variable within the function or any outer nested function. Without redeclaraion, such access works for both reading and writing and executing `myVar = 2` within the function will update the value of the global variable.
2. Executing `window.myVar = 2` within a function will only update the value of a global `myVar` variable if it was declared using `var`. It may create a window property but will not update the value of a global `let` variable.

So the value of `myVar` shown in an alert after the function has been called depends on

- whether the global declaration has been shadowed by re-declaring the variable within function scope (either locally within a function or in an outer function),
- whether `myVar` was referenced using an unadorned  identifier or as a named window property, in conjunction with
- whether `myVar` was originally declared using `var` or `let`.